# Issue with a skiping of first row

Tags: python, list

I understand that it skips the first row in the file because of header, but how can I avoid it? The syntax must be exactly the same as it is below.

File contains: `Rabbit, Pig, Dog, Horse, Bird`

```
try: 
    file = open("file.txt")
    line = file.readline()

    animals = [] 
    for line in file:
        animals.append(line.rstrip()) 
    animals.sort()
    print(animals)
finally:
    file.close()
```

Output is `['Bird', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Pig']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `readline()` is called, it reads a line from a file and moves the cursor to the beggining of the next line.

In your code, `line = file.readline()` reads the first line and moves the cursor to the second line. As a result, your `for` loop starts from the second line of the file. If there is no particular reason you need it, just delete it. If you do need it, just append the `line` variable in the list and then do the sorting.

Comment: Glauvus, thank you for explaining! I thought using that 'line = file.readline()' in a loop, but I was wrong! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problems is the line variable, it reads a line and it is never used. You should consider using another name for the variable file because it is a keyword. Also it is good practice to open files in this format:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
f.read()
```

This should work.

```
try: 
    f = open("file.txt")

    animals = [] 
    for line in f:
        animals.append(line.rstrip()) 
    animals.sort()
    print(animals)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

you are reading the first line and  you are not doing something, you can include the first line in your output list: `animals = [line.rstrip()]`

or you can use the context manager:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    animals = sorted(l.rstrip() for l in fp)
```